# Rewrite nested SELECT as INNER JOIN MySQL

Tags: mysql, select, nested, inner-join

I have a query using WHERE IN statement

```
SELECT DISTINCT(col) 
FROM tab1 
WHERE id>71 AND id<5073 
AND col IN (SELECT DISTINCT(col) FROM tab0 WHERE id>55 AND id<320)
```

I tried to rewrite it using INNER JOIN, but I got fewer results. What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.col) 
FROM tab1 as t1 
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT DISTINCT(col) 
        FROM tab0 WHERE id>55 AND id<320
    ) AS t0o ON t1.col = t0o.col 
WHERE t1.id>71 AND t1.id<5073
```

Comment: 2nd query has restriction on `t1.col = t0o.col` that 1st query doesn't have

Comment: just have to ask,why you need to join one table.. what result do you need

Comment: Thanks, it was a typo, that solved it :)

Comment: what do you mean.. ok seen it

Comment: Before I edited the query, there was SELECT DISTINCT(t1.col) 
FROM tab0 as t1 instead of SELECT DISTINCT(t1.col) 
FROM tab1 as t1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct a.col
FROM tab1 AS a
JOIN tab0 AS b
WHERE a.id > 71 AND a.id < 5073
AND b.id > 55 AND b.id < 320
AND a.col = b.col
```